# Merge two model instance in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I want to merge two model instance in Django.
For example I have:

```
person1:
    id=1
    created=(some date)
    name=None
    last_name=none

person2:
    id=None
    created=None
    name=John
    last_name=Daw
```

and result should be:

```
result:
    id=1
    created=(some date)
    name=John
    last_name=Daw
```

Now I do it iterating in __dict__ property, but maybe somebody knows better way.
I look for something like jQuery.extend function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this way, first find out those values not null in `person2`:

```
person2_dict = {k: v for k, v in person2.__dict__.iteritems() if v is not None}
```

Merge them into the target `person1`:

```
person1.__dict__.update(person2_dict)
person1.save()
```

Comment: @MaxKharandziuk I think `dict.update` is close to `$.extend`.

Comment: I said about extend function just for example:)

Answer (score 4):

Two third party libraries can help deduplicate Django models:

Django Extensions' [merge_model_instances](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/merge_model_instances.html) management command.

[Django Super Deduper](https://github.com/mighty-justice/django-super-deduper/tree/master/django_super_deduper)